# Strange error: Error in if () { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame called studenti:

[image]

When I tried to run the following code:

```
maschi = data.frame()
indice = 0

for (i in seq_along(studenti$sesso)) {
    if (studenti$sesso[i] == "M") {
        indice = indice + 1
        maschi[indice,] <- studenti[i,]
    }
}
```

the following error appeared "Error in if () { :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed".

My goal is to copy in the data frame maschi only the rows of the data frame studenti such that sesso=M.

---

EDIT

[image]

---

EDIT: dput output

```
structure(list(sesso = c("F", "M", "M", "M", "M"), altezza = c(168, 
182, 176, 193, 178), peso = c(60, 75, 72, 95, 68), scarpe = c(41, 
43, 45, 45, 45), caso = c(7, 9, 5, 6, 7), matricola = c(1, -1, 
-1, -1, 6), mese = c(11, 5, 9, 5, 7), giorno = c(7, 2, 29, 8, 
12)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The data you pasted at the end is not readable as the spaces are all gone.  Can you use `dput` so that I get the structure of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to use `subset`

```
maschi <- subset(studenti, sesso == "M")
```

---

or `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
studenti %>%
     filter(sesso == "M")
```

---

The `for` loop can be done with `rbind`

```
maschi <- studenti[0,]
for(i in seq_len(nrow(studenti))) {
     if(studenti$sesso[i] == "M" & !is.na(studenti$sesso[i]))  {
        maschi <- rbind(maschi, studenti[i,])
   }
}
```

---

Also, in the OP's code, we just need

```
maschi <- studenti[0,]
indice = 0

for (i in seq_along(studenti$sesso)) {
    if (studenti$sesso[i] == "M" & !is.na(studenti$sesso[i])) {
        indice = indice + 1
        maschi[indice,] <- studenti[i,]
    }
}
```

-output

```
> maschi
  sesso altezza
2     M     182
3     M     176
4     M     193
```

-Update using the OP's update data

```
> maschi
  sesso altezza peso scarpe caso matricola mese giorno
2     M     182   75     43    9        -1    5      2
3     M     176   72     45    5        -1    9     29
4     M     193   95     45    6        -1    5      8
5     M     178   68     45    7         6    7     12
```

#### data

```
studenti <- data.frame(sesso = c("F", "M", "M", "M"), altezza = c(168, 182, 176, 193))
```

Comment: Hi @akrun the request is to create a new data frame from the scratch. Does the command maschi <- studenti[0,] create a data frame maschi with the same columns of studenti?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi yes, it does.  I assume that you want to bind only rows that have 'M' in 'sesso

Comment: why did you write maschi <- rbind(maschi, studenti[i,])? I should need a new index instead of i in order to put the rows one below the other (see indice in my question)

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi but, why you don't want to do this easily instead of making things in a roundabout way

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi your code also works if we just have `maschi <- studenti[0,]`

Comment: Thank you @akrun It's very strange I get again the same error: Error in if (studenti$sesso[i] == "M") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi have you tried my reproducible example with the. code I showed i.e. `maschi <- studenti[0,]`

Comment: your example works fine. I'm trying to understand what I did wrong...it seems that R doesn't like the sesso column (it's a character column)

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi can you show the `str(studenti)`. Do you have `NA` elements?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi i think you have `NA `lements, change the code to `if (studenti$sesso[i] == "M" & !is.na(studenti$sesso[i])`

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi can you check it.  I was able to reproduce the same error with NA elements.  So, the correction should work

Comment: I changed the type of the columns, now only sesso is a character. Now the error is: Error in studenti[0, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi why is `studenti[0, ]` I meant to create the `maschi` as `maschi <- studenti[0,]` as initial data

Comment: yes, the first command is maschi <- studenti[0,]

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi i can't reproduce that error though

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi if you can update your post with a small `dput` of your example that gives the error then i can test

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi `I changed the type of the columns, now only sesso is a character.`. How did you change it?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi that was the issue. You need `studenti[] <- Map(`class<-`, studenti, c("character", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))`

Comment: i.e. `studenti[] <-` instead of just `studenti <-` because `Map` returns a `list`, but we want the class to be data.frame.  `[]` preserves the class of the original data

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Can you try the code now.  It should work because the error was because of the `list` class and not data.frame

Comment: same error related to to if statement...I added the dput output of a piece of the data frame studenti

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi One `)` was missing in the code. corrected

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi can you test it now.  It is working for me with your data now

Comment: amazing! Now everything works very well

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi thanks.  It was my mistake.  I didn't check the `)` earlier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237797/discussion-between-gennaro-arguzzi-and-akrun).